# SQL - DATEDIFF analysis across different rows / CURSOR usage

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I need to identify bookings for a hotel that are made within 5 days of each other.

I need the query to check the other Holiday dates (for each supplierID), and identify just the ones that are within 5 days of each other.

I've heard that using CURSOR is a the way to do this, perhaps with a combination of DATEDIFF and OVER (PARTITION by SupplierID), but have no experience of the CURSOR function and how to use it.

The output should be something like this...

[image]

And my query so far is...

```
SELECT 

    SupplierID AS 'Hotel',
    B.ID AS BookingID,
    B.Depart

    ?? AS '5 days apart'

    FROM  Bookings B
    ORDER by B.SupplierID, B.Depart
```

Help much appreciated...

Comment: Which dates you are comparing? Any next one date? In your output example your last columns shows pairs, not the "analyzis" of next date. I think you could write CASE statement and check if there any dates with DATEDIFF(day,table1.date,table2.date)<=5.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to use a cursor here, you can do it with a query like this:

```
select b1.SupplierID sid1, b1.ID id1, b1.Depart d1,
   iif(count(*)>1,'y','n') as within5days
from Bookings b1
left join Bookings b2
on b1.SupplierID=b2.SupplierID and abs(datediff(day, b1.Depart, b2.Depart))<=5
group by b1.SupplierID, b1.ID, b1.Depart;
```

If you have trouble with the performance, then a cursor might be a better choice, indeed.

edit: added the restriction in the on clause to join only the same suppliers

Answer (score 0):

```
create table datestable (hotel int, booking int, holday date)
insert into datestable values
(1,111111,'20140604'),
(1,111112,'20140606'),
(1,111113,'20141012'),
(1,111114,'20141230'),
(5,211111,'20150214'),
(5,211112,'20150217'),
(5,211113,'20150328'),
(5,211114,'20150523')

SELECT *
    ,(CASE WHEN (
        SELECT TOP 1 1
        FROM datestable d2
        WHERE d1.hotel = d2.hotel AND d1.holday <> d2.holday
        AND datediff(day, d2.holday, d1.holday) BETWEEN - 5 AND 5
        ) = 1 THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END
    ) as '5 days apart'
FROM datestable d1
```